# Are the unanswered questions in The 4400 ever answered in the follow-up novels?

Tags: novel, adaptation-comparison, the-4400

The great science fiction TV series The 4400 was canceled after four seasons, with a cliff-hanger ending.  Now there are two novels, Greg Cox's "Welcome to Promise City" and David Mack's "Promises Broken", which apparently show what would have happened if the series had continued.

But my question is, do these follow-up novels resolve the questions left unanswered by the series?  In particular, these questions:

1. Why did an entity from the future make Kyle Baldwin kill Jordan Collier?
2. What happened to the entity from the future that had been possessing Kyle after Sean expelled it from Kyle's body?
3. What happened to Jordan Collier after he died?
4. How did the White Light cult get the information about the future recorded in their book?
5. Why did the faction of the future that sent the Marked want to keep the future the way it is?

Can someone who has read the novels tell me which if any of these five questions are answered?  And what other unanswered questions are answered?

Comment: Why not read them and find out?

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, I'm somewhat reluctant to read them because I'm afraid that they'll just give plot details without answering the mysteries.

Comment: ..but you'll have an answer..won't you? How would you be worse off than you are now?

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, I'm reluctant to waste my time if I'm going to be left empty-handed when I'm done.  So I'm hoping someone who's read the novels can tell me if questions are answered.

Comment: I think its a fair question, but you might want to break the questions out into separate question posts since there are a lot of questions in this single post.

Comment: I agree, please edit this to focus on a single question. I’d gladly answer any of these questions, but they should be separate.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your questions are answered or you can infer an answer from the series itself.

1. There is a group from the future that doesn’t want the future improved because they at elites living in a walled area while the rest of the world lives in a horrible dystopia.
2. This question not really answered. The nanomachines are destroyed. Maybe that destroys the entity it carried.
3. After Jordan Collier was resurrected he wandered, had visions, didn’t really know who he was, and began a cult among the rejects and homeless in society.
4. Not really answered either, but since the future can time travel perhaps they went back and created it?
5. That faction is cold, heartless, and likes their position as an elite and to hell with everyone else. In other words they are evil and selfish.